# Can I remove duplicates AFTER MAPPING my object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an Object called `data` contains list of arrays. I just map my `data` to get a specific column data as follows.

```
 const DisplayData = data
    ?.filter((vendors) => vendors?.vendors != null)
    .map((risk) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td
            className="link_hover"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(vendors(risk.vendors));
            }}
          >
            <Link
              className=" link_hover text-decoration-none second-color  vendor_list_font_size"
              to="/vendor_critical_details"
            >
              {risk.vendors}
            </Link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
```

From the above code I got list of ``vendor` names. but I got duplicate names. Is there any trick to remove duplicates from the result?

Thanks

Comment: Use a reduce instead of filter

Comment: @mplungjan can you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce instead of filter

```
const vendorList = data
?.reduce((acc,vendors) => {
  const vendor = vendors?.vendors ?? null
  if (vendor != null && !acc.includes(vendor)) acc.push(vendor)
  return acc
},[]);
const DisplayData = vendorList.length === 0 ? "" : vendorList.map(risk => ...
```

Comment: this code reduces the array size from 11 to 8(removed duplicates) but values are hidden. I cant see list of vendors

Comment: Please post an example of the data. For example I do not understand this statement `vendors(risk.vendors)`